# Fill a cube with GameObjects and change scale

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, scaling, gameobject

Hey there my game is an 2d game (based on the game "Popcorn Chef"),
and my problem is:

I have a square with an edge collider arrounding it. The shape is like an 'U' for filling it up with circles. I have a scipt to spawn circles in it but I have to scale the circles up. So they need more space in the square. But after scaling up:

```
gameObject.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(minSize, maxSize, scaleSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

the circles are glitching to the left and right out of the square and that's horrible. They should go up like boiling water, which need more space in a pot.

Thanks guys!

Comment: rigidbody physics engines, such as the one unity uses, don't recognize objects that can change shape (which by definition aren't rigid bodies). You'll either need to implement your own physics calculations--very difficult--or find a way to approximate non-rigidbody deformation with rigidbodies that works "enough" for your needs--easier, but specific for your needs. These are each too broad to address in a single answer so you'll want to narrow the scope of the question if you want substantial help.

Comment: Try one of the following: reduce the resize speed, make the circle smaller, make the square larger, reduce the amount of circle in the square.